# psexec: "Access is denied" (Win10 =>XP)

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, psexec

## GOAL

Attempting to access XP_BOX on the LAN from a Windows 10 box:

## CONFIGURATION

PsExec v2.2 installed on Win10 from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx)

## OBSERVATION:

```
C:\> psexec \\XP_BOX -u XP_BOX\username  -c ipconfig

Password:
Couldn't access XP_BOX:
Access is denied
```

## UPDATE TO OBSERVATION

Observed successful console-redirection:  ran the XP_BOX command prompt on the Win10 box as if the command prompt were running locally

> psexec \\XP_BOX cmd

Interestingly enough: I could not list directories of 'net use' configured drives: a question for another thread.

Succesfully returned the ipconfig command:

```
win10>psexec \\XP_BOX ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter LAN:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.112
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
ipconfig exited on salve with error code 0.
```

## WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED

I am able to share out a folder from the XP_BOX

```
C:\>net use Q: \\XP_BOX\Dropbox
The command completed successfully.
```

I have verified that XP_BOX resolves to a LAN ip address via ping.

I have tried this command with the XP_BOX off and it hangs (expected because of no response from XP_BOX).

I have tried the [secpol update procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/301867/psexec-logon-failure-unknown-user-name-or-bad-password) on the XP_BOX:

> Start>Run>secpol.msc

Navigate to

> Local Policies>Security Options

Set the policy "Network Access: Sharing and security model for local accounts" to (Just hit OK: Don't close this out as we will be changing it back).

> Guest only – local users authenticate
>   as Guest

Open a command box and run (Dont close this either)

> gpupdate /force

Go back and set the policy "Network Access: Sharing and security model for local accounts" back to

> Classic - local users authenticate as
>   themselves

Again run

> gpupdate /force

Test from Win10 box

Reboot

Test from Win10 box

## QUESTIONS

*If you have had success sending psexec command from a WIN10 to an XP box please state this in your response.*  Because there are many versions of Windows, it is important to frame any comments so as to understand the context.

1. What can be done to diagnose the root-cause of the error message?
2. What corrective action can be tested?
3. Is it possible to run psexec from win10 to an XP box?

Comment: Ideas to try: Can you do File Sharing?  How about using Services.msc/RPC?  If either of these fail, I would expect PSExec to similarly fail.  (See the "Inside PSExec" section of [Mark Russinovich's article on Windows IT Pro](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec).)  I didn't post this as an answer as there's a lot of guesswork, but if the hunch appears right and resolves the issue, I can make a fuller answer out of this.

Comment: Yes, XP_BOX can share out a folder to Win10.  Details posted in OP.  Please elaborate on questions regarding Services.msc/RPC: how would I test that?  Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry to have wasted time by not reading the question more slowly.  To test that in Windows 10, go to Start, Windows System, Command Prompt.  Run: "`start services.msc`"  Or find it under Control Panel, Administrative Tools.  (Might not be in XP home, but in XP Pro and some newer versions of Microsoft Windows.)  In the left frame, right-click on the computer (the top-most option) and choose "Connect to another Computer/PC".  P.S., nothing specific about services.msc.  I just chose that rather at random; alternatives eventvwr.msc or compmgmt.msc ought to be just as effective for this test

Comment: From Win10box (services.msc): successfully connected to XP_BOX (XP Professional).  Tried additional command line tests from WIN10 and update the OP

Comment: PSExec Home Page, today (discussing the program's version 2.11 from March 2014) says "Runs on" "Client: Windows Vista and higher." "Server: Windows Server 2008 and higher."  Might need an old version.  Might want to try alternatives, like using WMI (built into Windows).

Comment: @TOOGAM: comments are appredciated.  I am using PSExec V2.2   Please clarify how Windows Management Instrumentation is an alternative.  As I understand it, The purpose of WMI is to define a proprietary set of environment-independent specifications which allow management information to be shared between management application

Comment: That's frightening, because it appears that the last 3 official versions were V2.0, V2.1, and V2.11.  Did you get this from an unofficial source?  To quote my own info, WMIC /NODE:remoteSysName /USER:UserName PROCESS CALL CREATE "CMD /C dir C: >> C:\Temp\output.txt"

Comment: Okay, looked this over again.  So you did run "psexec \\XP_BOX ipconfig" successfully?  So the only time it failed is when you included "-u XP_BOX\username  -c"?  It looks like "-c" may be your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54326/discussion-between-gatorback-and-toogam).

Comment: I've read the new chat but decline to discuss there.  Discussions that go into chat are prone to being deleted.  I will offer this (perhaps final) hint for this question: You may be better off creating a new question.  You provide lots of details, and the idea of doing that seems nice, but it doesn't seem very focused; you seem to jump around a bit leading people to wonder the point.  e.g., why \salve?  Why secpol.msc?  Question #1 is for the root cause... of what?  It's just a tough question, likely leading to many ignoring it completely.

Comment: I suspect -c tries to write an executable and permissions may be an issue.  I suspect there may be authentication issues which you can re-produce by going to the XP_BOX and seeing if you can use runas with the same entire /user:XP_BOX\username

Comment: @TOOGAM, your advice, feedback and time is appreciated.  Thank you.   It is a tough question